# Destino de formulario Laravel desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, blade

Tengo un formulario en una vista blade, así:

```
<form id="delete_form" method="post" action="">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" id="delete_type" name="delete_type" value="">
</form>
```

El valor de `action` debería ser algo como `{{ route('personas.destroy', ['persona'=>$persona]) }}`

Hasta aquí, todo bien. El problema es que el objeto `$persona` tiene que seleccionarse dinámicamente desde javascript, porque hay varios enlaces que deben poder lanzar ese formulario, y cada uno debe pasar un objeto `$persona` distinto.

He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, pero la `action` del formulario no se construye correctamente.

¿Cómo se puede hacer un formulario en el que el objeto pueda cambiarse dinámicamente en cada llamada?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso como es un tema dinámico, el action lo deberías construir "a mano" desde javascript en tus diferentes eventos, por ejemplo a continuacion te dejo un simple ejemplo de como editar el atributo action del form, al capturar el evento click de dos botones:

```js
$("#borrar1").click(function(){
  $("#delete_form").attr("action","http://tusitio/borrar/"+$(this).data("id"));
  console.log($("#delete_form").attr("action"));
  //una vez editado puedes submitear el form.
  //$("#delete_form").submit();
});

$("#borrar2").click(function(){
  $("#delete_form").attr("action","http://tusitio/borrar/"+$(this).data("id"));
  console.log($("#delete_form").attr("action"));
  //$("#delete_form").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="delete_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" id="delete_type" name="delete_type" value="">
</form>
<button id="borrar1" data-id="1">Test1</button>
<button id="borrar2" data-id="2">Test2</button>
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me has dado la pista que necesitaba. A partir de esa idea, he puesto en el formulario el helper route, y luego en jquery sólo modifico la parte del id. Gracias.